# Define trigger through Spring JPA

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, database-trigger

I'm using Spring Boot with Spring JPA and Postgres DB. All tables and it's columns are defined from code (i.e. Entities). Now I want to set trigger before pulling data from DB (BEFORE SELECT) and update it accordingly, but EventListeners can't help me here, because they support all operations but BEFORE SELECT.

So my question is, is there any way to set up BEFORE SELECT trigger on DB through code (like tables are defined with Entities)?

Answer (score 2):

You can't define triggers through annotations at entities if this is what you mean by "defined with Entities". But you can use [Spring Boots features for initializing the database](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html):

Either provide your own `schema.sql` script or use something like Flyway or Liquibase.